# Setting HTML required attribute in Django formsets

Tags: django, django-templates

To achieve client-side validation making the user to fill out non-null fields before submitting, I use the following code:

```
class MyForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MyForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)   
        for field_name, field in self.fields.items():
            field.widget.attrs['class'] = 'form-control'
            if field.required == True: 
                field.widget.attrs['required'] = ''
```

This translates to the following html in the template:

```
<input class="form-control" ........ required="">
```

Now, when I use formsets, the required HTML attribute does not appear in the tempalte. The question is, how do I make Django formsets inherit this **required** attribute from the original forms - if it's possible whatsoever?

```
MyFormSet =  modelformset_factory(MyModel, fields=(...))
formset = MyFormSet(queryset = MyModel.objects.filter(...))
```

Answer (score 1):

How about creating formset from MyForm?

```
MyFormSet = forms.formset_factory(MyForm)
```

Comment: formset_factory does not seem to allow for filtering queryset

Comment: But it's correct that formset_factory really solved the problem of required.

Answer (score 0):

After spending three hours, I've solved the issue by [setting a custom form](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#changing-the-form) in modelformset_factory. Maybe it will be useful for someone else

```
MyFormSet =  modelformset_factory(MyModel, MyForm)
formset = MyFormSet(queryset = MyModel.objects.filter(...))
```

Specifying MyForm effectively **tells Django to inherit all widget attributes** that you have once declared in the MyForm definition.

Using formset_factory is for some reasons a headache for me, primarily because it accepts values instead of querysets which means I have to bother about foreign key relationships.